# JavaScript: setAttribute works but .style doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

**NOTE:** I have no problem using setAttribute in my project. This is merely a question as to why something is not working.

I have made a basic `.js`, `.html` and `.css` file. Here is the code for each:

```js
//Load Document
window.onload = () => {
  //get Body Height and Width
  let body = document.body;
  let html = document.documentElement;
  let bH = Math.max(body.offsetHeight, body.scrollHeight, body.clientHeight, html.offsetHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.clientHeight);
  let bW = Math.max(body.offsetWidth, body.scrollWidth, body.clientWidth, html.offsetWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.clientWidth);
  console.log(`Body Height: ${bH}px`);

  //get document elements
  const menu = document.getElementById("getMenu");
  const menuMarginTB = (bH - menu.offsetHeight) / 2;
  //menu.setAttribute("style", "margin:"+menuMarginTB+"px auto;");
  menu.style.margin = `${menuMarginTB}px auto;`;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Random Website</title>
  <link href="./main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script defer src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="getContainer" class="container">
    <div id="getMenu" class="menu">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have commented out `setAttribute` because it works, but when I try to use `.style.margin` it doesn't work. There are no errors that pop up in Console (I'm using Google Chrome). I don't know why it's not working. Here is what I tried:

1. I tried using `document.onload` and `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...);` but these failed. I am currently using `window.onload`, and it doesn't work either.
2. I tried removing `defer` from the script tag; however, `defer` is only suppose to run this script after every HTML element was parsed (to my knowledge), I don't know how removing or keeping it in will have an affect on `.style.margin`, if any.
3. I tried changing the `id` name from `"menu"` to `"getMenu"`. I assumed that having the same name for both id and class was not only bad practice, but affecting the way `.style.margin` worked. However, it didn't really seem to help when I chaned it.
4. I tried `concatenating` the string instead of `interpolating` it. I assumed that maybe template interpolation didn't work in the was I was using it, but string concatenation didn't seem to help.

[**NOTE:** I may have tried more things, but I can't remember.]

I think this problem extends to all `.style` properties because upon looking at the Dev Tool for Google Chrome, all of the properties are blank, even though they are assigned in the `.css` file.

[Proof 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjE7f.png)
I already assigned `height` to `400px` but here it shows up as `""`. The same thing happens after I run the last line of the `.js` file is run using a breakpoint. When I hover over `menu.style.margin`, it, too, results in `""`. [Proof 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPgcz.png)

The only thing I can think of is that maybe something didn't load in causing this to happen, but even it it didn't load in, I don't know how to fix it. Any help on the matter is much appreciate.

Comment: When manipulating style directly you needn’t use the semicolon. You can use it when setting an attribute because an attribute value is always a primitive string.

Comment: *"...because upon looking at the Dev Tool for Google Chrome, all of the properties are blank, even though they are assigned in the .css file."* - On this note, check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information): "The style property is not useful for completely learning about the styles applied on the element, since **it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the <head> section, or external style sheets.***

Comment: Well asked question, shame it boiled down to a stray semicolon.

Comment: @j08691 Though on that note, I still think this question has some merit, as opposed to "close-as-typo". Per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269606/2026606: *"If you think the answer to the question might help someone else in the future (for example, when they run into the same problem and go searching for a solution), post a good answer and keep it around.

Otherwise, if it's truly a bone-headed typo, delete the question. [...] **This is a well-asked question [...] about an unintuitive problem that is very likely to be useful to others.**"* - I feel this is applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a very simple error :)

`element.style = value` only works if `value` is a valid value for this css property. In the code you posted it is not: you may not include the semicolon in the string.